# Cycle Through Divs Stacked on Each Other

Tags: jquery, each

I have 5 divs stacked on top on each other like this:

```
<div container>
   <div1>
   <div2>
   <div3>
   <div4>
   <div5>
</container>
```

Below the divs are prev and next arrows. I'm trying to cycle through the divs in each direction on click. I can't get it working. Below, is what I'm thinking. Can anyone help me?

```
var objects = ['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4', '#div5'];

function next () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $(objects[i]).each?
        $(objects[i]).push or pull
        $(objects[i]).css(z-index)
        $(objects[i]).insertAfter
    }
}
```

I know there are other methods, but I can't make major additions in my code. I'm somewhat restrained to this setup.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `cycle through the divs`? Hide all but one, and show the next on click?

Comment: Exactly. It's like an image gallery. I'm trying to hide the top div and show the next in the stack. Thanks :)

Comment: `<div container>` **is invalid HTML**.

Answer (score 0):

If your divs are siblings, you can use jQuery's .next() and .prev() to get the next/prev div and do you work accordingly.

http://api.jquery.com/next

http://api.jquery.com/prev

Comment: Thanks!

    $(objects[3]).next().hide()

How can I rearrange the stacking order of the array?